Rewrite this stored procedure so that it passes up this error through the output variable?
I moved a stored procedure from one database to another and that went fine. I then went to run it and got these errors:

Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.myStoredProc, Line 159 [Batch Start Line 2]
Invalid object name 'missingTable'.


Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure dbo.myStoredProc, Line 159 [Batch Start Line 2]
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.

The problem turned out to be that one of the tables was missing, but I want to know if there is a way for my stored procedure to pass up the first error through an output variable.
Here is the general structure of my stored procedure. I use the @Status variable to pass up either 'OK' (if there are no issues) or an error message. In the example below, the table myTable doesn't exist. When I go into SSMS and right click > Execute Stored Procedure, it returns the errors above and shows that @Status = null and Return Value = null.
create procedure myStoredProc
    @InputParm nvarchar(100),
    @Status nvarchar(4000) output
as
begin
    set nocount on

    set @Status = 'OK'
 
    begin try
        --...compute stuff

        begin tran
            delete from myTable

            insert into myTable 
                select 1
        commit tran
    end try
    begin catch
        if xact_state() <> 0 
           rollback tran

        set @Status = (select error_message())
    end catch
end


You can read which errors aren't caught by TRY CATCH: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

SQL Server's try-catch only handles execution errors. Since non-existing object errors are detected and error in the compilation phase you'd need to cause that to happen in a nested context such as either a nested stored procedure or dynamic SQL via sp_executesql, e.g. db<>fiddle.

This error handling is horrible anyway. Why not just remove it all, use SET XACT_ABORT ON; and just let the error propogate?

@Charlieface why is it horrible? I need to catch any error and pass it up to the calling program where it'll be shown to the user. My method in the question seems to meet this need for the most part (except for the error I'm asking about)

Why do you need to catch it? It will be passed up anyway. There is no need for a @Status variable, the client application can simply use catch or other normal error handling. It's horrible because it: doesn't handle multiple errors at the same time (this is impossible to handle within TSQL), and doesn't handle rollbacks correctly. What you should have done if you really needed that rollback is to use a savepoint, and check XACT_STATE=-1 then just THROW; to rethrow it. Anyway, you don't need this because SET XACT_ABORT ON handles rollbacks.

If you are missing a table in the database, this should be caught in developer testing, long before formal testing, and much longer before you need to present any errors to the users.

As @Charlieface commented, I also believe it is not necessary to place a try-catch block in the nested usp. I also don't believe You need an output parameter. Instead, what might help You is an outer usp, that uses a try-catch block to collect information on the success or lack thereof of the execution of the nested usp.
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS #outer_sp 
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #outer_sp 
AS
SET XACT_ABORT, NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE 
  @result_BIT BIT
  ,@result_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000)

-- ... other work ...

/* the "experiment" with uncertain outcome: */
BEGIN TRY
  EXEC myStoredProc @InputParm 
  
  SELECT @result_BIT = 1, @result_MESSAGE = 'success' 
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
  
  SELECT @result_BIT = 0, @result_MESSAGE = 'ERROR: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

SELECT 
  "@result_BIT"      = @result_BIT
  ,"@result_MESSAGE" = @result_MESSAGE
    
-- ... other work ...

GO


The reason I need to pass up an error is because the calling program needs to show it to the user. Is there a way to catch this error without having to write an outer SP?

@Morty I believe @Charlieface in his latest comment describes correctly what you need. No try-catch block and SET XACT_ABORT ON. A potential error will be returned to the calling program. If, say, Excel sends the EXEC statement to the db, and an error occurs, an annoying sound will ding and a small window will pop up and show that error message, that explains that an object name is missing (or whatever). What do You need beyond that?
